# Can't install Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay: they required higher minimum deployment target

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-in-app-messaging

I'm trying to use Firebase In-App Messaging and just added some lines to my Podfile.
But when I run `pod install`,  I got an error message below:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I also tried `pod install --repo-update`, but got the same error.
How can I install the pod?

My cocoapod is 1.5.3, and Xcode is 10.1.
Here's my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'iOSTestApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for iOSTestApp
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'  
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay'

  target 'iOSTestAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

And the result of `pod outdated`:

```
- Firebase 4.4.0 -> (unused) (latest version 5.12.0)
- FirebaseAnalytics 4.0.4 -> 5.3.0 (latest version 5.3.0)
- FirebaseCore 4.0.9 -> 5.1.7 (latest version 5.1.7)
- FirebaseDynamicLinks 2.1.0 -> 3.1.1 (latest version 3.1.1)
- FirebaseInstanceID 2.0.5 -> 3.3.0 (latest version 3.3.0)
- FirebaseMessaging 2.0.5 -> 3.2.1 (latest version 3.2.1)
- GoogleToolboxForMac 2.1.3 -> (unused) (latest version 2.1.4)
- nanopb 0.3.8 -> 0.3.901 (latest version 0.3.901)
- Protobuf 3.4.0 -> 3.6.1 (latest version 3.6.1)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am having a nearly identical issue.

Answer (score 1):

`InAppMessaging` requires Firebase 5.x. Do a `pod update` so that your existing pods will update past their currently install versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging' #, '~> 2.0.5'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
pod 'Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay'
```

Save podfile.

1. Quit xCode
2. Delete Pods folder and Podfile.lock
3. run pod install --verbose
4. if issue is resolved, thats good.

*Else do following steps*, **it will update all your Pods**

5. pod update

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Before you begin, you need a few things set up in your environment:

- **An app with Firebase enabled**: If you haven't already, add [Firebase to your iOS project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).
- **Xcode 9.2 or higher**: Firebase In-App Messaging needs a relatively-recent version of Xcode to run. You can find the latest Xcode version at [Apple's Xcode site.](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)
- **CocoaPods 1.4.0 or higher**: Firebase In-App Messaging uses CocoaPods to manage dependencies on iOS. You can install it from the [CocoaPods site](https://cocoapods.org/).

One more thing to do, update Firebase SDK using **pod update 'Firebase'** and then after add **Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay** dependency in a pod file.

It will start installing once execute **pod install** command in terminal.